# what is the latest angularjs stable version that supports ie?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, frontend

What is the latest stable angularjs version?
Does it support internet-explorer 9 and above completely?

what are the challenges i need to face if I build a website completely on angularjs and run it on internet-explorer 9?

Comment: I believe this can be found on AngularJs site.

Answer (score 2):

You can use v1.5.1  latest version which is support ie9 and above.
Check IE compatibility of angular js [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie)